# Get a value from HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery

Given a javascript object (this.activeCell) that contains the following html:

```
<td class="gt-col-mygrid1-ordered_cells gt-cell-actived-editable gt-cell-updated"><div class="gt-inner  gt-inner-left ">156</div></td>
```

How can I get that 156 into a var?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given `this.activeCell` is a `DOM Element`, you can pass it into the `jQuery` constructor and create a `jQuery` object. Then, call the `find` method passing a `selector` that retrieves your target element. Finally, calling `.text` on the selected element you can retrieve your text:

```
var text = $(this.activeCell).find('div.gt-inner').text();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the html() function in JQuery

Answer (score 0):

Try `parseInt($(.gt-inner));`

The class can be any class the `div` has.

Answer (score 0):

```
var text = $(this.activeCell).filter(function() { return this.nodeType == 3; });
```